# Error using Apollo Angular 2 for Angular ts-invariant/lib/invariant.d.ts:7:78

Tags: angular, typescript, apollo, apollo-client, gql

I am unsure as to why I am getting this error please help.

```
ERROR in node_modules/@apollo/client/node_modules/ts-invariant/lib/invariant.d.ts:7:78 - error TS1144: '{' or ';' expected.

7 export declare function invariant(condition: any, message?: string): asserts condition;
                                                                               ~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Visual Studio? I recently had this error, in my case I believe it was due to and outdated version of typescript. I created an angular project using visual studio, which uses angular version 8 and saw this error after installing angular-apollo as per their docs
https://apollo-angular.com/docs/get-started/

The solution for me was to update the project from angular version 8.2 to 9.1 using this https://update.angular.io/
After that I was able to install angular-apollo using angular schematics, as noted in the link to the docs above.

After upgrading you may also find another error when running ng build at the @angular/router compilation step. As per the answer at this link [Angular 8 to 9 upgrade error when trying to build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60386358/angular-8-to-9-upgrade-error-when-trying-to-build), open `src/main.ts` and remove this line;

`export { renderModule, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';`